# Using ".measure" on a View with a Ref, x and y coordinates always are 0 when run in Android but works fine on iOS (React Native)

Tags: react-native

I've assigned a view with a Ref, and I'm using this reference to get the coordinates of the view. It works fine on iOS, where I get a Y-value where the View is located. However, on Android, the Y-value is always zero.

I've read that you should use collapsable={false} on the View you are measuring, but the only thing that did was to no longer return "undefined" but instead return "0".

I've created a snack for the issue, will appreciate any feedback on how to resolve this.

https://snack.expo.dev/@minifisk/quiet-cashew?platform=ios